# Is ReSharper working properly with VisualStudio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Yet, has anyone tried whether ReSharper is working properly after installing SP1?

Wonder if I should install Service Pack 1 right away or rather wait for an update of ReSharper or any official statement from JetBrains. Since for me VisualStudio without ReSharper already feels like coding with Notepad. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just installed SP1 a few hours age and R# works just fine a far as I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is crashing for me now after installing SP1. Not really sure what's up with that. Looks like it has to do with Resharper from what I can tell.

Edit: Actually, looks like dotCover was having the issue.